# Get parameters from request according to the name of variables

Tags: php

I want something like this:

I have send a request to server which contains my_par=test.

I can get it like this $my_par= $_REQUEST["my_par"]. this is the normal way.

But I want if my variable name is match to the request name then it take the value of that parameter automatically.

so I want a function like **set_variable_value(array($my_par,$my_par2),$_REQUEST)**, then it should set the value for variables like this:

```
$my_par = $_REQUEST["my_par"];
$my_par2 = $_REQUEST["my_par2"];
```

is it possible to achieve such a thing in PHP?

**OR in a simple way**

if I send a request like this my_par1=test&my_par2=test2, I want to access them just by add $ at the beginning of their name like this:

$my_par1 and $my_par2

Comment: If your question is _“does PHP support an if/else construct?” … then the answer is yes.

Comment: @CBroe it should be dynamic, i have edited the question plz take a look again.

Comment: Are you talking about `extract($_REQUEST);`? Still a bad idea.

Comment: why it is a bad idea @CBroe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the `$_POST` array, like this:

```
extract($_POST);
```

This will give you variables named after `$_POST`'s keys, with corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but this can be achieved by using `parse_str()`:

```
$query =  http_build_query($_REQUEST);
parse_str($query);
```

So, if the request was like below:

```
test.php?foo=test1&bar=test2&baz=test3
```

... you can simply access the variables using their query parameter names, like so:

```
echo $foo;
```

would output:

```
test1
```

With the above code, you may accidentally override already defined variables. If you use the second parameter of `parse_str()`, you can store the variables in an array, instead:

```
parse_str($query, $params);
```

That way, you don't set/override variables in the current scope.